# Should I use forward declaration for library types?

Tags: c

As I understand, whenever possible, it is better to use forward declaration in header files and use include in the source file. All examples I've seen in the site were about user defined types (maybe my misunderstanding), what about library types? For example this one [`GInetAddr`](https://developer.gnome.org/gnet/stable/gnet-inetaddr.html#GInetAddr). In this case should I forward declare like:

```
typedef struct _GInetAddr GInetAddr;
```

Or use `#include <gnet.h>` in header file?

Comment: Don't do e.g. forward declarations of things system header files (those included with angle-brackets `<>`). Either include the system header-file in your header file, or include the system header-file in all source-files including your header file (I personally tend to lean toward the latter style).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, Thanks. This is what I'm doing right now (i.e. using include) Because I thought they are not in my control and may change any time. But I had doubts when I saw `typedef struct _GInetAddr GInetAddr;` in the reference manual.